# How can I get a folder from remote machine to local machine?

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying `scp -r usernameipaddress:/path /pathwhereIwanttocopy`, but I am getting it as connection refused.

How can I get it? How can I get connected?

Comment: why on earth did you close this? seems relevant.

Comment: It was supposed to get moved but they made a mistake.

Comment: 'on the machine of my college machine' what does that even mean?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The -r flag should work. In your example you seem to be forgetting the name of the folder you want to copy. Try:

```
scp -r nameOfFolderToCopy username@ipaddress:/path/to/copy/
```

to copy a folder from your local computer to a remote one. Or

```
scp -r username@ipaddress:/path/of/folder/to/copy /target/local/directory
```

to copy a folder from a remote machine to your local one.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm having myself returning to this question over and over, maybe I should try to remember it. :|

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check out [`rsync`](http://www.comentum.com/rsync.html). It has lots of options for handling duplicates, permissions etc.

```
rsync -r username@computer:/path/to/source /path/to/dest
```

or for upload

```
rsync -r /path/to/source username@computer:/path/to/dest
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder called `working` in your user directory, all you need is:

```
scp -r username@ipaddress:working ./
```

It's likely you'll get "Permission Denied" with this:

```
scp -r username@ipaddress:/working ./
```

---

Can you check to see if the `ssh` service is running on the remote machine? If you can login, try:

```
ps -aux | grep sshd
```